# Problema con group by en mysql y lentitud en la consulta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente situación con una consulta **MYSQL**. Lo que me sucede es que tengo dos tablas, que la estoy uniendo por **LEFT JOIN** para traer todos los registros que estén en la primera tabla que es **tabla3**.

En la segunda tabla **pay_amb** donde se guarda el **id** de relación,  los tengo repetidos por lo que estoy usando un **GROUP BY** para agruparlo y así evitar registros duplicados a la hora de mostrar mi consulta.

Los que me está sucediendo, es que cuando coloco el **GROUP BY** a mi consulta me genera un **time out** porque se excedió el máximo tiempo de ejecución de mi script que está en **500**. He probado quitando el **GROUP BY** y la consulta se me ejecuta sin problema. Vale destacar que tengo colocado el **index** en los siguientes campos.

1. table3.policynumber
2. pay_amb.p_number
3. pay_amb.commission
4. pay_amb.month

A continuación le dejo la consulta para ver si me pueden ayudar. 
Gracias.

> Nota:Estoy manejando entre las dos tablas como un promedio de unos
>   30000 registros.

```
SELECT 
  table3.policynumber AS id, 
  CONCAT(table3.`names`,' ',table3.lastname) AS nombre, 
  @var1 := SUBSTRING(pay_amb.month FROM 1 FOR 4) AS anio,
  (
    SELECT 
      SUM(pay_amb.commission) 
    FROM pay_amb 
    WHERE pay_amb.p_number = table3.policynumber 
      AND SUBSTRING(pay_amb.month FROM 1 FOR 4) = @var1 
      AND SUBSTRING(pay_amb.month FROM 6 FOR 2) = '01'
  ) AS ene
FROM table3 
  LEFT JOIN pay_amb 
  ON table3.policynumber = pay_amb.p_number 
GROUP BY pay_amb.p_number
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Aquí les dejo el resultado del **explain** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos el explain plan? esos 500 son ms? si es asi, es muy pero muy poco inclusive para los pocos registros que tenes...

Comment: No te convendría mejor tener guardados ya los datos en la tabla para evitar realizar funciones de substring?,

Comment: Parecería como si el `WHERE` y el `JOIN` fuesen redundantes en cuanto a la columna `p_number`. Y quizá haya más cosas a mejorar, pero nada se puede decir sin conocer el modelo de datos completo y lo que hace la aplicación. Otra cosa extraña es que uses `SUBSTRING` para una columna que, por el nombre, hace pensar que se trata de un mes del año. ¿Esa columna no es `DATETIME`? ¿Por qué no usas `MONTH` en caso de que lo sea? ¿O acaso estás almacenando un mes solo sin contar con día y año?

Comment: En le campo **month** estoy guardando la fecha complete **Y-m-d** y después la separo con un **substring** utilizando la sección que necesito el tipo de campo es un campo **date**, a continuación les dejo el resultado del **explain** que me devolvió la consulta.

Comment: Hola y gracias a todos, ya logre resolver el problema lo que me sucedía es que en una tabla estaba usando el contejamiento de **UTF-8** y en la otra **LATIN** cuando coloque las dos tablas con UTF-8 se me resolvió el problema  y la consulta se me ejecuta  rápido y sin **time out**. Les dejo el comentario por si alguien mas le sucede.